# creating wifi miniport in ubuntu 12.10 to connect android phones

Tags: 12.10, wireless, madwifi

I'm from chennai ,India . I have a usb dongle to connect the internet so how can i share this connection through the wifi . i used the wifi hotspot but i was not able to even detect it from my android phone . Please help . Thanks in advance